# Let $f$ be a function analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ \\{0,1,2,...}. Suppose $f$ has the following properties.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a function analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ \{0,1,2,...}. Suppose $f$ has the following properties.

(i)$f$ has a simple pole at $z=0,1,2,...$

(ii)$f(-1)=1$

(iii)$f(z-1)=zf(z)$ for $z\neq0,1,2,...$

Find the value of the residue of $f$ at $z=0$ and prove that
$nRes_{z=n}{f(z)}=Res_{z=n-1}{f(z)}$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$

Comment: From $f(z) = \frac{f(z-1)}{z}$ the residue at $0$ is immediate

Answer (score 1):

$Res_{z=0}f(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} zf(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} f(z-1) = f(-1) = 1$. [Note we are allowed to use $zf(z) = f(z-1)$ since we are looking at $z$ near $0$ and not $z = 0$.]

Now, using this, $Res_{z=1}f(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} (z-1)f(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} f(z+1)z = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z+1}z$ where I used property (iii) applied to $z+1$. But this is $\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z) = res_{z=0} f = 1$.

Similarly, one can compute residues at $z=n$ for $n \ge 2$. I'll leave this to you.